# Algorithm and Implementation of Microflow Engine

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, business-process-management

I am working on microflow engine (backend) which is a process flow to be executed in runtime.

Consider the following diagram where each process is a Java Class. There are variables out from process to in to another process. Since flow is dynamic in nature, very complicated flow is possible with many gateways (GW) and processes.

Is DFS/BFS a good choice to implement the runtime engine? Any idea guys.

[image]

Comment: dfs/bfs for what exactly?

Comment: Implementing the runtime engine so that flows might go either Process1 > Process2 > Process4 or Process1 > Process3 > Process4 in the above case.

Comment: (I think the goal (evaluate/simulate compound flow process models) was clear enough from the outset. Please put in the question _what_ the microflow runtime engine is to search for depth or breadth first. It would help me if you mentioned where the terminology you are using originates - IBM WebSphere/BPEL?) One problem in model evaluation is to pick an evaluation order. One strategy is to try to evaluate that part first that has the greatest effect overall - guessing, e.g., by biggest relative change in boundary condition(s). (Keeping a priority queue/to-do list.)

Comment: @PujanSrivastava was there a resolution to this after all?

Comment: @A_A I am still working on this but figured it out already how to approach.  Taken some idea from your answer and I will post my resolution at the endof the day or weekend. Thanks for your kind patience.

Comment: @PujanSrivastava No worries, it's an interesting subject, so I thought I might check back anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the given example is concerned, it is solved via Depth First Search (DFS), using the output node as the "root" of the tree.

This is because:

- For the output to obtain a value, it needs the output of Process4
- For Process4 to produce an output, it needs the outputs of Process2 and
  Process3
- For Process2 / Process3 to produce an output, they need the
  output of GW
- For GW to produce an output it needs the output from
  Process1

So, the general idea would be to do a DFS from each output, all the way back to the inputs.

This will work almost as described for anything that looks like a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG, or in fact a Tree), from the point of view of the output.

If a workflow ends up having "cycle edges" or "feedback loops",  that is, if it now looks like a Graph, then additional consideration will need to be given to avoid infinite traversals and re-evaluation of a Process output.

Finally, if a workflow needs to be aware of the concept of "Time" (in general) then additional consideration will need to be given so that it is ensured that although the graph is evaluated progressively, node-by-node, in the end, it has produced the right output for time instance (n). That is, you want to avoid some Processes producing output AHEAD of the current time instance just because they were called more frequently.

A trivial example of this is already present in the question. Due to DFS, GW will be evaluated for Process2 (or Process3) but it doesn't have to be re-evaluated (for the same time instance) for Process3 (or Process2). When dealing with DAGs, you can simply add an "Evaluated" flag on each Process which is cleared at the beginning of the traversal. Then, DFS would decide to descend down the branch of a node if it finds that it is not yet evaluated. Otherwise, it simply obtains the output of some Process that was evaluated during a previous traversal. (This is why I mention "almost as described" earlier). But, this trivial trick will not work with multiple feedback loops. In that case, you really need to make the nodes "aware" about the passage of time.

For more information and for a really thorough exposition of related issues, I would strongly recommend that you go through [Bruno Preiss' Y logic simulator](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus3/book.pdf). Although it is in C++ and is a logic simulator, it goes through exactly the same considerations that are faced by any similar system of interconnected "abstract nodes" that are supposed to be carrying out some form of "processing".

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can imagine traversal. I don't see search, or what has to be found (as opposed to be computed).